# OData returning 'Cannot find the services container for route 'odata-Unversioned'

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to setup a new .NET Core 3.1 API with OData.

I have a working .NET Core API in 2.2 with OData, so I am going off of that one.

I am using three OData specific nuget packages: *Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData v7.3.0*, *Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning v4.1.1* and *Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning.ApiExplorer v4.1.1*.

I keep getting the folloing response when I send a GET request to my controller:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the services container for route 'odata-Unversioned'. This should not happen and represents a bug.
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.PerRouteContainerBase.GetODataRootContainer(String routeName)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.CreateRequestScope(HttpRequest request, String routeName)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.CreateRequestContainer(HttpRequest request, String routeName)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Match>b__0()
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.GetODataPath(String oDataPathString, String uriPathString, String queryString, Func`1 requestContainerFactory)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, String routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
  at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.UnversionedODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, String routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteConstraintMatcher.Match(IDictionary`2 constraints, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, RouteDirection routeDirection, ILogger logger)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
  at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Note I have the requirement that the API needs to be versioned. I am not sure if versioning has something to do with this error, but the old .NET Core 2.2 API that I have uses OData versioning as well. Does anyone know what the services container is for a route?

I setup my project similar to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/.
I also even tried setting it up exactly as is done in the blog post, however I could not even get OData to work without versioning. When I tried removing versioning, I kept getting a 404 and it couldn't hit the route. Is my routing setup correctly?

Here is the ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add API versioning
    services.AddApiVersioning(options => options.ReportApiVersions = true);

    // Add OData
    services.AddOData().EnableApiVersioning();
    services.AddODataApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

    // Add support for controllers and API-related features
    services.AddControllers(mvcOptions => mvcOptions.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
}
```

Here is the Configure

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    var apiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
    {
        routeBuilder.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
            routes.MapVersionedODataRoute("odata", "api/v{version:apiVersion}", app.GetEdmModel(), apiVersion));
    });
}
```

Here is the extension method `GetEdmModel()` I am using above

```
public static class ODataExtensions
{
    public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var model = GetEdmModel(app.ApplicationServices);
        return model;
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);

        // Entities
        builder.EntityType<Object>().HasKey(x => x.Id);

        // Controllers
        builder.EntitySet<Object>("Object");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

Here is the controller

```
[Route("odata")]
[ApiVersion("1")] 
public class ObjectsController : ODataController
{
    private readonly ILogicService _logicService;

    public AlternateIdsController(ILogicService logicService)
    {
        _logicService = logicService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_logicService.Browse());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller name in the GetEdmModel() method and the actual name of the Controller class differed by one 's'.

Comment: Unfortunately, a mismatch in names will cause this bug to manifest. Glad you found the culprit. The fix will hopefully provide a better experience when someone makes this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this is actually a bug, but it **only** seems to manifest when a URL is requested for an entity that doesn't exist. This is being tracked as [Issue 553](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/553) with a fix forthcoming.